# Low-pressure pump-fed rocket engine?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, launch-vehicle, pressure

I saw the above suggested in [LEO on the Cheap](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/LEOonthecheap.pdf). In P.130 it says:

> A compromise between high-performance/lightweight pump-fed vehicle designs
> and cost-optimized pressure-fed vehicles with heavier structure is a
> possibility, by using pressure-fed engine designs with simple, low-pressure
> turbopump assemblies. This approach retains the simple, inexpensive engines
> typical of pressure-fed vehicles, but it uses low-cost pumps to avoid the heavier
> pressurized tank structure needed by pressure-fed boosters.

So basically we get 15-40 bar chamber pressure, fueled by a pump that could have been mass produced for a jet engine - [or a diesel engine!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_pump#:%7E:text=Pumps%20for%20direct%2Dinjection%20diesel,and%20helix%2C%20and%20metering%20unit.), and relatively light tankage.

So, who has tried to do this on a rocket with the purpose of reducing cost (of course there is an example in the book) and what was the outcome?

Comment: Wernher von Braun? http://www.v2rocket.com/start/makeup/design.html 23 bar Pc

Comment: @OrganicMarble Okay, that answered my question, but did not answer my question. So I'm editing my question to make sure that the answer to my question answers my question.

Comment: That's an interesting document you linked. I skimmed the parts about shuttle; it seems sensible. I'll enjoy reading it, thanks.

Comment: At that point your efficiency have dropped so much that solid rocket are becoming competitive.

Comment: @user3528438 Are you sure about that? I mean, maybe that applies to the lower end of the chamber pressures running at sea level (pressure ratio, thermal efficiency), but the majority of a rocket's time is spent significantly above that.

Comment: @user3528438 in any case, solid fuel is expensive and rather myopic.